# Grails - reading config property in resources.xml

Tags: grails, javabeans

In my Grails application, I have a java file which I need to create bean from resources.xml.
And I need to pass url which is specific to each environment.

How can I read the config path property like below :

```
     <bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
        <property name="maxTotal" value="5" />
        <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="6000" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jedisPool" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jedisPoolConfig" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="${grailsApplication.config.baseUrl}" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="7890" />
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="6000" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="redisConnectionPool"
          class="com.app.util.RedisConnectionPool">
        <property name="jedisPool" ref="jedisPool" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that the bean has to be defined in `resources.xml`, as opposed to `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`?

Comment: Because my Grails version is a bit older and all the supporting plugins are kind of depricated. Hence thought of adding an independent Java plugin directly.

Comment: "Because my Grails version is a bit older and all the supporting plugins are kind of depricated." - I don't think we ever released a version of Grails that didn't support defining beans in `resources.groovy`.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.grails.org/4.0.11/guide/spring.html#propertyPlaceholderConfiguration

application.groovy

```
baseUrl='whatever'
```

resources.xml

```
<bean id="jedisPool" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jedisPoolConfig" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${baseUrl}" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="7890" />
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="6000" />
</bean>
```